# Simple ether transfer from parity wallet

Tags: wallets, parity

I installed parity wallet and deposited 5 ether. 
Now I am trying to transfer it to another address and "parity signer:pending" appeared
and it is going on for three hours and on.

How long does it take to transfer an ether to another address?

Comment: The screen says "The transaction is in progress.  Waiting for authorization in the Parity Signer."

Answer (score 1):

It takes only seconds to send a transaction, and only a few minutes for the transfer to finalise.

What you need to do is use the Secure Transaction Signer to authorise the transaction. The documentation is sparse, but this is what you should see: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Parity-Wallet.

The Secure Transaction Signer is a feature of the Parity wallet, but some people prefer to use the official Ethereum wallet (Mist). It is possible to use Mist with Parity.

To use Mist, you must first run parity with the `--geth` flag like so: `parity --geth`. (If you are on Windows, just modify the shortcut `parity.exe --geth`, it works the same).

Now open Mist, and you can send transactions without the additional transaction signing step.

Comment: Thanks for your answer 
I read the link you suggested.  It did not help. 
https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/Parity-Wallet.

I removed and reinstalled the parity wallet. 
It has 5 ethers in the account.
Could you explain how to transfer my ether out of this wallet without 
"paroty signer: pending"appearing on the screen or within seconds?

Comment: You will find Mist much simpler, and if you follow my instructions given it will use the account in your Parity wallet without needing any additional import steps.

Comment: is there a way to have access to my ether in parity wallet using other wallet?  I imstalled and searched for a way to install my parity wallet address into the MIst, bur there seems to be no way.   Please help.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm explaining in my answer. To help you more I will need to know what OS you're using and whether you have been able to follow my steps or not.