# Parity Signer: Pending

Tags: parity, cpp-ethereum

I am trying to use the send on a certain block feature with parity wallet.
I am on windows 7 and installed parity and successfully have it running in the background with the --warp option (I can see the terminal running in background). When I go to send eth I get the following window:
Parity Signer: Pending
I tried everything in this post with no luck
[Simple ether transfer from parity wallet](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15612/simple-ether-transfer-from-parity-wallet)

My ether is now stuck in the wallet. any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use Google Chrome, Internet Explorer had problems.